# Webpage opening as https and geting error message

Tags: html, http, url, web, https

I have multiple webpages, the main page is index.html, and I have several others, page2.html, page3.html etc as an example.. However one of my other pages, say page2.html, when it comes up on google search, attempts to open up as https instead of http, causing an error. It is just an informational page so it does not require https or an ssl certificate.

How do I set it so that from the google search the page only attempts to open as http?

My main index.html page, from google search, opens as http as it should, and the other pages to my knowledge are configured the same?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "What Google chooses to link to" is not a programming problem. You might be able to get help on [the webmasters stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

> It is just an informational page so it does not require https or an ssl certificate.

Is just wrong.

Without https you can't guaranty integrity, witch mean that ISP, wifi hot-spot and others can (and do) manipulate you page to add tracking-cookies, ads or anything else.

It's mean you don't have confidentiality either, which your visitors could expect.

> How do I set it so that from the google search the page only attempts to open as http?

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066 can help you.